# Class suggestion for 60 twinking

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have just noticed how popular level 60 twinks are. I am familiar with
all the classes.

What classes do you guys suggest ? I believe paladin are the most common because
they only need a weapon to be strong. Being a spellcaster you need a lot of spellpower
to see a difference.

I was thinking about making a Affliction Warlock (I like the dot-n-run pattern) or a shadow priest.

I would just say that some classes are easier to twink then others. It's much more easier to get high agility for a rogue/hunter then it is to get spellpower with a spellcaster.

I would like to make a twink that wont require 4 months of works to get a single
rare drop that increase my spellpower for only 20.

Right now, I have seen paladin on top of the Alterac Valley KBs. I know
it's a matter of playstyle but will any other classes be able to do decent damage as well without having to spend months of eqs gathering?

As for the new patch (new talents). Do we still see level 60 twinks around?

Comment: As written, this question is, quite frankly, far too subjective to get a useful single answer. In truth, you can twink with any class at level 60, and they all have differing advantages and disadvantages. A better question might be, once you've decided what class to twink, a request for gear, spec, or resource recommendations to get you started, or, alterntely, a request for an evaluation of the *specific* advantages and disadvantages of twinking a particular build. (i.e. 'In what ways are Warlock twinks effective at level 60?')

Comment: To add to what LessPop stated, this is subjective. However, if you let us know what you are looking to do with the class, and what your interests are. Someone might be better equipped to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: So, just to be clear, is your question then "are caster classes viable as level 60 twinks"? Because if so, I can write up an answer.

Comment: Yes I would like to get an answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is cast from afar "dot-n-run pattern", than you are already on the right track. I would go with a lock.

If this is your mindset I would guess you would also be interested in rogue, because you can do similar hit and run tactics as a twink. Lock down the clothies and then sprint away. Overall any and every class can be turned into a fun level 60 twink, it just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: What is a decent +spellpower a warlock can reach at level 60? Thank you

Comment: Anything above 600 is insane for 60, and hard to get. Best thing to do is just take a look at some of the level 60 twink guilds, and view their twinks on the armory.

Comment: Given that tier 3 is no longer obtainable -- wouldn't tier 2 be the best possible gear? Or are there Outlands BoEs to consider?

Comment: @Raven I know some use Outlands blues from Blood Furnance and Ramparts + quest completes. Greens are not better than tier 2 however.

Comment: I dont believe my 60 twink will be able to use BoA or Outland's equipments since that character must be kept on a seperate account with no expansion enabled. Right?

Comment: @Cybrix to tell ya the truth I'm not sure. I thought level 60 twinks played level 60 twinks whether BC was enabled or not. Never thought that Blizz might separate the twinks based on their accounts. That seems highly unlikely to me. But that's a good question. If you do not have BC, it is likely in BG's that you will have to play twinks that have BC content.

Comment: To not go above level 60 you must either have XP turned off or that account must not be BC-enabled. With xp turned off you will have to wait a while to join BGs. That's why I believe players keep their twinks on a separate accounts.

Comment: Agreed, when I think of "twink" I think of XP turned off. Any other way is just trying to kill newbies leveling. Which according to most people who play twinks, is not what it is about. I guess some people found a way to get around that by playing level 60s with no BC. However, that would be really hard to get a twink that could dominate even the newbies. And I would not be surprised if Blizz did something about that in the future, like possibly force those players to play against the XP off twinks.

Comment: I talked to two twinks yesturday (enh shaman and a mm hunter) on AV. Both dont have XP-turned off but they do play on a Classic WoW account. I describe twinks being someone who is better equiped then the average. And for the informations, both of them ended top KBs/Damage in AV yesturday.

Answer (score 1):

With BG's you want to be able to do crowd control. I have a pally but I get constantly pwnd by a locks or shamans. So, a 'lock or Shaman is probably the most effective. Pally's are easy to spec up but don't forget the warrior for dual weapon wielding.

If you can, level your lock with a higher level buddy/guildie to speed up grinding. Also, if you have other toons with lots of honor you can buy BOA gear from vendors in Wintergrasp or their respective capital cities and pass the gear around to your twink as it "re-specs" to the level of that toon.

My preference is a lock..

Comment: I dont believe I can use BoA items if my account contains only classic WoW (no expansion enabled). Or maybe I could send him BoA when my character is on a WoTLk account and then transfert that toon to a classic account. But I dont believe the BoA items will remains.

Comment: If you have WotLK you can transfer items to the lower toons on an account. In the absence of BOA gear, grind your way to 60 with a buddy/guildie. Blizz are well aware of time it takes to level all the classes and so I would expect DPS spec of any class will get you to 60 fastest. It's alot of work to twink to 60. I have seen many players create level 20 twinks. If you have the means upgrade to WotLK. It's worth it. Just so much more gear and engaging raids and new BG's. The install is quite fat though. My WoW is fully upgraded and is 20GB's

Answer (score 1):

A **dk**, after they finish doing all the quests for the talents go well armed, compared with a pj level comes up normally.